# Google Cloud Pub/Sub client library for Java not using local emulator

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to use Google cloud Pub/Sub emulator for testing my scala app. [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) states the following -

> Run the env-init command to determine and set the environment variables used by the emulator. Note that after following these instructions, the Google Cloud Pub/Sub client libraries in your code call the API running in the local instance instead of the production API.

But when I publish a message or create a topic it gets executed in the cloud and not on my local emulator. I have confirmed that the environment variable is set correctly using `println(s"ENV: ${sys.env("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST")}")` which prints `ENV: localhost:8085`.

I tried forcing the library to use my local setup as follows

```
val settings = TopicAdminSettings.defaultBuilder()
  .setChannelProvider(InstantiatingChannelProvider.newBuilder()
    .setEndpoint("localhost:8085")
      .setCredentialsProvider(TopicAdminSettings.defaultCredentialsProviderBuilder().build())
    .build())
  .build()

val topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create(settings)
topicAdminClient.createTopic(topicName)
```

This way I succeed to send a request to my local setup but that results in the following error -

```
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:49:11 午後 io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[pubsub] INFO: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:49:11 午後io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[pubsub] INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:49:11 午後 io.gapi.emulators.netty.NotFoundHandler handleRequest
[pubsub] INFO: Unknown request URI: /bad-request
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:49:35 午後 io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[pubsub] INFO: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:49:35 午後 io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[pubsub] INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:49:35 午後 io.gapi.emulators.netty.NotFoundHandler handleRequest
[pubsub] INFO: Unknown request URI: /bad-request
```

I started the emulator as follows -

```
PC-12041:random kakaji$ sudo gcloud beta emulators pubsub start
Password:
Executing: /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/platform/pubsub-emulator/bin/cloud-pubsub-emulator --host=localhost --port=8085
[pubsub] This is the Google Pub/Sub fake.
[pubsub] Implementation may be incomplete or differ from the real system.
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:59:21 午後 com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.Main main
[pubsub] INFO: IAM integration is disabled. IAM policy methods and ACL checks are not supported
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:59:21 午後 io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl <init>
[pubsub] INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@77b52d12] Created with target localhost:8085
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:59:21 午後 io.gapi.emulators.netty.NettyUtil applyJava7LongHostnameWorkaround
[pubsub] INFO: Unable to apply Java 7 long hostname workaround.
[pubsub] 6 14, 2017 2:59:21 午後 com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.Main main
[pubsub] INFO: Server started, listening on 8085
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Cloud Pub/Sub docs mention](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#accessing_environment_variables) that Java and C# client libraries do not automatically connect to the emulator host via `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST`.

Instead, you should do the following (extracted from the docs):

```java
String hostport = System.getenv("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST");
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(hostport).usePlaintext().build();
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = NoCredentialsProvider.create();

// Publisher that connects to the emulator
TopicName topicName = TopicName.of("my-project-id", "my-topic-id");

// Set the channel and credentials provider when creating a `Publisher`.
// Similarly for Subscriber
Publisher publisher =
    Publisher.newBuilder(topicName)
        .setChannelProvider(channelProvider)
        .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build();
```

You may want to check if `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST` is set and only then set `NoCredentialsProvider` and the custom `ManagedChannel` on the builder.